# Ember: use segments instead of query parameters for API?

Tags: ember.js

Currently my Ember-cli application calls my API in this way:

```
apiurl:3000/ingredients?name=something
apiurl:3000/ingredients?filter=som?limit=10
```

I'd like to make Ember query for:

```
apiurl:3000/ingredient/something
apiurl:3000/ingredients/som?limit=10
```

But I've two problems:

1. `WARNING: Encountered "ingredients" in payload, but no model was found for model name "ingredient" (resolved model name using myapp@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("ingredients"))`
2. I can't find a way to make Ember use URL segments instead of query parameters.

I think I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into overriding your RESTAdapter's buildURL method?

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL

As what you're trying to do appears to be quite specific you could use this method to override the building of these requests, while at the same time keeping the default Ember model/params implementation the same.

Comment: I've read around and seems like the expected API endpoint should be `/ingredients` and I should use the query parameters for all the rest? If so then I don't even need to override the buildURL, it looks just a little weird.

Comment: Yes that's right - The RESTful way to do things would be to have all of your ingredients available at /ingredients then, if you need to find a particular one, you can add something like a `?filter=cheese` query param to find all ingredients which match, each of which would be available at /ingredients/:id

Having /ingredient and /ingredients is not recommended, as it's not particularly RESTful, which is what Ember tends to expect.

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I ask Ember to call ingredients/:id if it only uses url query params?

Comment: Well if you know the id then you can just do a `this.store.find('ingredient', id)`, which will make a call to ingredients/:id and return whatever's there. If you don't know the id and you're just trying to find something then you'll probably do `this.store.find('ingredient', {filter: 'cheese'})`.